# Compute the sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \cdot 2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

What would be the sum of the following series?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \cdot 2^n}$$

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\ln(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n$$

Can you recognize $x$ here?

**See also**: [Taylor series for $\log(1+x)$ and its convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594838/taylor-series-for-log1x-and-its-convergence)

Answer (score 0):

$a_n = \dfrac{(2^{-1})^n}{n} = \dfrac{a^n}{n}$.

**Hint:** find $\left(\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{x^n}{n}\right)'$

Comment: could you elaborate more on the hint part please?? Thanks

Comment: 1. Find derivative which turns out to be a geometric series that is easy to calculate the sum. 2. Integrate the sum get back the original series. 3. Plug $x = 1/2$ to get the final answer.