# Evaluating the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k2^k}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k2^k}$.  In fact I'm trying to find that $C$ for which $P(\{k\})=\frac{C}{k2^k}$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb{N}$ but presumably the intended solution goes by finding the value of the sum.  I want to check if the following is a correct calculation / proof.  If I write out the first several terms I don't see a way to make things better.

$$1/2 + 1/8 + 1/24 + 1/64 + ... $$

I thought about the trick used for weakly proving the geometric sum formula:  Call the sum $s$, then

$$s = 1/2 + 1/8 + ... $$
$$4s = 2 + 1/2 + 1/8 + ... $$
so

$$3s = 2$$

so $s=2/3$.

Comment: This is $\ln 2$.

Comment: The problem is that $4\times (1/24)\neq 1/8$, so your attempted cancellation breaks down. Instead, you need to look at the Taylor series for $\ln(1-x)$ and figure out what value to plug in for $x$.

Comment: See if these search results help: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum%5Climits_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bk2%5Ek%7D%24&p=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compute the sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \cdot 2^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106587/compute-the-sum-of-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n-cdot-2n)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\ln(1-x)=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{x^k}k\enspace\text{for }\;\lvert x\rvert<1.$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: if $$f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{z^n}{n}$$ differentiate $f$ term-by-term.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry This is not a complete answer but i hope it can help you

Taylor Series Centered at 1
$(0 < x \le2)$

$ln(x) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{(n+1)}{(x-1)^n\over n}= (x-1) - {(x-1)^2\over2} + {(x-1)^3\over3} - {(x-1)^4\over4} + ... 
+ (-1)^{(n+1)}{(x-1)^n\over n} +....$

$\ln({1\over2}) = -{1\over2} - {1\over 8} - {1\over24} - {1\over64} - ... $

$\ln2^{-1} = -{1\over2} - {1\over 8} - {1\over24} - {1\over64} - ...$

$-\ln2 = -{1\over2} - {1\over 8} - {1\over24} - {1\over64} - ...$

$\ln 2 = {1\over2} + {1\over 8} + {1\over24} + {1\over64}+  ...$

Comment: Not a complete answer?  You underestimate what qualifies as complete.