# How to calculate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\times 2^n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

everyone! I just would like to know how you can calculate $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\times2^n}$$ I know this does converge, but I don't know how to calculate it numerically.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You must mean $\sum\limits_{\color{red}n=1}^\infty$, and it's $\ln 2$

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106587/compute-the-sum-of-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n-cdot-2n)

Comment: Yes! Thank you @J.W.Tanner. I've edited my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compute the sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \cdot 2^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106587/compute-the-sum-of-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n-cdot-2n)

Comment: Yes! Thanks! @rtybase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$\ln(1+x)=x-\dfrac{x^2}2+\dfrac{x^3}3-\dfrac{x^4}4+...$

Now take $x=-\frac{1}2$ and note that $\ln(\frac12)=-\ln2$.