# How to find the sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n+1)4^n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to find the sum of the following series:

$$1+\frac13\frac14+\frac15\frac1{4^2}+\dots?$$
The general term is $u_n=\frac1{(2n+1)4^n};n\geq 1$.

Comment: If $u_n=\frac{1}{2n+1}\frac{1}{2^n}$ then the sum is $$1+\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{2^2}+\ldots$$

Comment: Do you know how to find closed forms of series like $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$ for $|x| < 1$?

Comment: It appears the general term is $u_n=\frac 1{2n+1}\frac 1{4^n}$

Comment: [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+n+%3D+0+to+infinity+of+%281%2F%28%282n%2B1%29*%284%5En%29%29%29) gives the result as this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT:

$$\ln(1+x)=x-\dfrac{x^2}2+\dfrac{x^3}3-\dfrac{x^4}4+\cdots$$

$$\ln(1-x)=-x-\dfrac{x^2}2-\dfrac{x^3}3-\dfrac{x^4}4-\cdots$$

$$\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)=?$$

Keep in mind : [Taylor series for $\log(1+x)$ and its convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594838/taylor-series-for-log1x-and-its-convergence)

Comment: excellent work +1

Comment: How did you get the idea that the series would be this one as there is no general technique to view that

Comment: @learnmore, Whenever you have something like $$\frac{x^n}n$$ think of log series for  $$\frac{x^n}{n!}$$ think of exponential series. For $$\frac{x^n}{r(r+1)\cdots(r+n-1)}$$ think of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Answer (score 4):

By using $\frac{4}{4-x^2}=\frac{1}{2-x}+\frac{1}{2+x}$ we have:
$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)4^n}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2n}}{4^n}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{4\,dx}{4-x^2}=\color{red}{\log 3}.$$

Comment: not so sure how you are removing the summation .Would have been nice if you could explain a bit

Comment: @learnmore: $\sum_{n\geq 0}z^n = \frac{1}{1-z}$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n+1}\frac{1}{4^n}&=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n+1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n+1}\\
&=2\,\text{artanh}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
\end{align*}
Since arctanh ($x$) can be expanded as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$ for $|x|<1$.