# Find the MacLaurin Series for $f(x)=\ln(√81-x^2)$

Tags: calculus

Find the MacLaurin Series for $f(x)=\ln(√81-x^2)$

I know that $\ln(\sqrt{81}-x^2) = 1/2(\ln(81-x^2)) = 1/2(\ln(9-x)) + 1/2(\ln(9+x))$

I need help finding the series, not the expansion.

Comment: Note that $\ln(81-x^2)=\ln(81)+\ln\left(1-\frac{x^2}{81}\right)$.
You probably know the Maclaurin series for $\ln(1+t)$. Replace $t$ everywhere by $-\frac{x^2}{81}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** You may just write
$$
\ln (9-x)=\ln 9+\ln \left(1-\frac x9\right)
$$ and use
$$
-\ln (1-u)=u+\frac{u^2}2+\frac{u^3}3+\cdots+\frac{u^n}n+\cdots,\qquad |u|<1,\tag1
$$ by putting $u=\dfrac x9$.

You may do the same for $\ln (9+x)$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\ln(9-x)=\ln9+\ln\left(1-\dfrac x9\right)$$

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920095/series-expansion-of-log1x2

and [Taylor series for $\log(1+x)$ and its convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594838/taylor-series-for-log1x-and-its-convergence)