# find radius and interval of convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3^n+(-2)^n}{n}(x+1)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

The series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3^n+(-2)^n}{n}(x+1)^n$$

I just do not know where to start here, I trues to substitute $t=x+1$ but it did not help much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac{3^n+(-2)^n}{n}(x+1)^n=\dfrac{\{3(x+1)\}^n}n+\dfrac{\{-2(x+1)\}^n}n$$

As $\ln(1+x)=-\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-x)^r}r$ is convergent for $-1<x\le1$

we can use [Taylor series for $\log(1+x)$ and its convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594838/taylor-series-for-log1x-and-its-convergence) OR [What is the correct radius of convergence for $\ln(1+x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356517/what-is-the-correct-radius-of-convergence-for-ln1x)