# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k+1}$

Tags: integration, limits, summation, riemann-integration

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k+1}$$

How can I find limit value of this? 
 I tried using Riemann, by supposing $x_k=\frac{2k+1}{n}$.

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{ \frac{2k+1}{n}} \frac{1}{n}$ 
$x_{k+1}-x_k=\frac{2}{n}$
$\frac{1}{2} \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{ \frac{2k+1}{n}} \frac{1}{n}$ 
$\frac{1}{2} \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^1\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{x} dx$ 
is this possible? thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k+1}=i\cdot\dfrac{i^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$$

Now $\ln(1+x)=x-\dfrac{x^2}2+\dfrac{x^3}3-\cdots$

$$\implies\ln(1+i)-\ln(1-i)=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{i^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$$

Now $\ln(1+i)-\ln(1-i)\equiv\ln\dfrac{1+i}{1-i}\pmod{2\pi i}$

$\equiv\ln\dfrac{(1+i)^2}2\equiv\ln(i)\equiv i\dfrac\pi2$

So, equating the real parts, $$2\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k+1}=\dfrac\pi2$$

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594838/taylor-series-for-log1x-and-its-convergence

Comment: thanks!!! but I don't understand where the $i$ came from? and why do you need to use $ln$?

Comment: hello, I tried to understand your answer, but still have some few questions, why did you use $ ln(1+ x)$? and also how can you change it to $\implies\ln(1+i)-\ln(1-i)=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{i^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$ thanks!?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Riemann sum is the right tool. Use the Taylor series of $x-\arctan(x)$ for $x=1$ centered at $0$. See [Why is $\arctan(x)=x-x^3/3+x^5/5-x^7/7+\dots$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29649/why-is-arctanx-x-x3-3x5-5-x7-7-dots) Hence the given sum is equal to $$1-\arctan(1)=1-\frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Comment: thanks I got this!. $ arctan(1)=1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}..= 1-arctan(1)=1-\pi/4$ , but that Riemann sum is totally wrong(?) because of alternating(?)

Comment: No, because $\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{x}$ is not integrable over $(0,1]$

Comment: @vik: actually you may remove the alternating signs by coupling adjacent terms, such that the problem boils down to computing $$\sum_{j\geq 1}\frac{1}{16j^2-1},$$ but Riemann sums are not the most suited tool for the explicit computation of such series.

Comment: @RobertZ thankyou so much! , is it because $\frac{1}{x} $ diverge? it produce $\infty$

Comment: @vik Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{\pars{-1}^{k + 1} \over 2k + 1} & =
\Re\bracks{\ic\,\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{\ic^{2k + 1} \over 2k + 1}} =
-\Im\bracks{\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{%
\sum_{k = 3}^{2n + 1}{\ic^{k} \over k} -
\sum_{k = 2}^{n}{\ic^{2k} \over 2k}}}
\\[5mm] & =
-\Im\braces{\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
\pars{-\ic + {1 \over 2} + \sum_{k = 1}^{2n + 1}{\ic^{k} \over k}} -
{1 \over 2}\sum_{k = 2}^{n}{\pars{-1}^{k} \over k}}}
\\[5mm] & =
1 + \Im\ln\pars{1 - \ic} = \bbx{1 - {\pi \over 4}} \approx 0.2146 
\end{align}

Comment: thankyou I try to understand, is this using complex plane? and also how can you change it to $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{\pars{-1}^{k + 1} \over 2k + 1} & =
\Re\bracks{\ic\,\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{\ic^{2k + 1} \over 2k + 1}} =
-\Im\bracks{\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{%
\sum_{k = 3}^{2n + 1}{\ic^{k} \over k} -
\sum_{k = 2}^{n}{\ic^{2k} \over 2k}}}
\\$?

Comment: @vik Note that $-1 = \mathrm{i}^{2}$ and "sum over $\texttt{odd}$" is equat to "sum over $\texttt{all}$" minus "sum over $\texttt{even}$". I put $\Re$ at the very begining because I know the final result will be a $\texttt{real}$ number. It makes easier the whole evaluation.

Comment: thankyou!! but still so hard for me to understand it, and I didn't understand how you get $-\Im ({ \lim_{n \to \infty}}\sum_{k = 3}^{2n + 1}{i^{k} \over k}-\sum_{k = 2}^{n}{i^{2k} \over 2k})$ , can you explain more how you got the "sum" $\sum_{k = 3}^{2n + 1}{i^{k} \over k}$  and why summation index start at $3$ and end at $2n-1$? and why you changed from $\Re$ to $-\Im$?

Comment: @vik The original index $2k + 1$ goes from $3 = 2 \times 1 + 1$ to $2n +1$. As the sum is over the $\color{red}{\texttt{odd}}$ values, it's equivalent to the sum over $\color{red}{\texttt{all}}$ allowed values (from $3$ to $2n + 1$) minus the $\color{red}{\texttt{even}}$ values (from $3$ to $2n + 1$, the even values are $4,6,\ldots,2n$ such that indexes in $k = 2k/2$ goes from $2 = 4/2$ to $n = 2n/2$).

Comment: ok i got it! but $\Im ({\lim_{n \to \infty}{{\color{red}{i}+ {\frac{\color{red}{i^2}}{2}} + \sum_{k = 1}^{2n + 1}{i^{k} \over k}} -
{1 \over 2}\sum_{k = 2}^{n}{\pars{-1}^{k} \over k})}}
$ 
if it start from $k=1$ like in red, why there is negative on your post? and also why you have to change index to 1? and also limit $n-> \infty$ here will make summation become zero? and how you got $\Im ln(1-i)$? thankyou!! sorry im asking too many questions !

Comment: @vik I have to "restart" the sum from $k = 1$ because, in that case, I'll have the $\ln$ series.